# Summation of Arithmetico-Geometric Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there a formula that exists that can help me find the series of an A.G.P. such as $n^3 \cdot 4^n$ or $7 \cdot n^2 \cdot 5^n$ or $3 \cdot n^6 \cdot 8^{n-5}$? I'm looking for a way to calculate the summation of such sequences.

Comment: I like to start with the formula for $\sum x^n$ and then apply differentiation and multiplication by $x$ as many times as necessary. For example after one such operation you get $\sum nx^n$ and so on.

Comment: For the last expression, you can substitute $m=n-5$ and expand the polynomial part. If you are interested in particular formulas, you can find them with Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @Peter , And how does the Wolfram Alpha calculator find the formula? That's what I'm interested in.

Comment: @KabEl The first comment gives a good approach for such formulas. Once you have the formula for $n^k\cdot a^n$ for $k=0,1,\cdots,m$ , you have it also for every polynomial with degree not exceeding $m$.

Comment: @Peter Can you direct me to an article or book that describes that process? My knowledge on A.G.P. is not that thorough and I wanted to learn more about it.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence) suggests that starting with $S_n = a + [a + d] r + [a + 2 d] r^2 + \cdots + [a + (n - 1) d] r^{n - 1}$ you consider $S_n-rS_n$ to reduce the question to an arithmetic series

Comment: @Henry . What if I have an alternative way of finding the summation formula? I read up on that technique and mine is different. How would someone go about publishing it,? I'm struggling with how to get it published.

Comment: Using approach from first comment to $n \cdot x^n$: $\sum_{n=1}^k x^n = \frac{x^{k+1}-x}{x-1}$. Differentiation by $x$ gives $\sum_{n=1}^k n x^{n-1} = \frac{k x^{k+1} - k x^k -x^k+1}{(x-1)^2}$. Let $k=l+1$, $n=i+1$, then $\sum_{i=0}^{l} (i+1) x^i = \frac{(l+1) x^{l+2} - (l+1) x^{l+1} -x^{l+1}+1}{(x-1)^2}$, also $\sum_{i=0}^{l} (i+1) x^i = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{l} i x^i + \sum_{i=1}^{l} x^i$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{l} i x^i=\frac{(l+1) x^{l+2} - (l+1) x^{l+1} -x^{l+1}+1}{(x-1)^2} - \frac{x^{l+1}-x}{x-1} - 1$, $\sum_{i=1}^{l} i x^i = \frac{l x^{l+2}-l x^{l+1} - x^{l+1} + x}{(x-1)^2}$.